# converting $scope into this with angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to convert my angularjs scoped functions and variables to using 'this'. I make a json request to github's api but my binding expressions show nothing. 
html:

```
<div ng-controller="MainController">


    <div>
        Name: {{ user.name}}
        Location: {{ user.location}}
        Image: <img ng-src="{{user.avatar_url}}" />
    </div>

</div>


 (function () {

            var app = angular.module("githubViewer", []);

            app.controller('MainController', function ($http) {


                this.user = [];
                this.error = "";

                this.onUserComplete = function (response) {


                    this.user = response.data;
                    console.log(this.user);
                }

                this.onError = function (reason) {
                    this.error = "Could not fetch the user";
                    return true;
                }

                $http.get("https://api.github.com/users/robconery").then(this.onUserComplete, this.onError);

            });



        })();
```

Comment: `this` when invoked from the callback is not going to be controller instance. There are numerous way to fix this.

Comment: This problem occurs because every new function defines its own `this` value. It could be fixed by using the new [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) syntax and transpile your code back to ECMAScript 5 using a tool like [`jstransform`](https://github.com/facebook/jstransform).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as the context of `this` has changed in the callback of `$http` you should declare a variable which you can use to keep the same context

```
     (function () {


       var app = angular.module("githubViewer", []);

    app.controller('MainController', function ($http) {

        var self=this;
        self.user = [];
        self.error = "";

        this.onUserComplete = function (response) {


            self.user = response.data;
            console.log(self.user);
        }

        this.onError = function (reason) {
            self.error = "Could not fetch the user";
            return true;
        }


       $http.get("https://api.github.com/users/robconery").then(self.onUserComplete, self.onError);

    });


    })();
```

Comment: I just tried it but not getting any output still.   http://plnkr.co/edit/mJbcyYrr71bRfSl5VEro?p=preview

Comment: Please if you can covert all the `this` that you want,in context of `Maincontroller` to interchange with `self` that i declared

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand. Could you edit my plnkr link above?

Comment: @runners3431 so its Helps?

Comment: i added your code to my plunkr link - http://plnkr.co/edit/mJbcyYrr71bRfSl5VEro?p=preview, but maybe the problem now is with my expression? I'm not getting any output.

Comment: The issue is that you need to use `controller as` syntax in order to make bindings work with controller instance (`this`) properties instead of $scope properties. I edited your plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/kGhxBTXPtJ9onEyklAWh?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be referring to approach that John Papa had recommended where you could create Controllers methods using `this`. However, I personally I failed to find the benefits of deviating from the standard but if you still want to to go for it you can read more about this this article that explains it:

http://www.johnpapa.net/angularjss-controller-as-and-the-vm-variable/

A quick sample demo:

```
app.controller('MainController', function(){
  var vm = this;
  vm. error = '';
  vm.onUserComplete = function(response){
    console.log(vm.error);
  };
```

});

Comment: I'm going with the this tehcnique shown in codeschool. I started up pluralsight course to reinforce the knowledge and they were using scope.

Comment: @runners3431 angular is based on injection pattern, this is simply deviating from the standard without a particular reason. It may be a matter of personal preference but I do not recommend the `this` approach. However, it is possible to use the `this` with angular as long as you set it to a local var prior any declaration.

Comment: @runners3431 You cannot rely on what `this` is going to be, it completely depends on the execution context unless you are using bound functions. I would go with caching `this`, another way you can do is using ES5 `bind`. `.then(this.onUserComplete.bind(this), this.onError.bind(this))`